# Instancing Actions?

Tags: animation, workflow, instances

I'm making character animations for a game project involving sword fighting. **I'm wondering if there is a way to instance action**s (or 'reference', not sure of the proper term for what I want).

What I mean is that I create a sword attack anim where the sword swing downwards. Then I take this action and copy it to tweak it a bit and create a sword attack where it swings diagonally.

Now if I want to make a few corrections on the animations.. like the feet perhaps, **is there a way to make the changes from the first animation automatically apply to all the other animations?** (50+ anims)

Or maybe do you have a better workflow to suggest? Because at the moment, if I want to fix something I'll need to manually fix it on every similar actions.

Thank you for reading.